# Compiling python3.7 with a custom openssl version

Tags: linux, python, docker, openssl

I'm trying to build a docker image containing Python3.7 configured with an Openssl version that allows SSLv2 and v3.

I tried the following:

```
FROM debian:9.7

WORKDIR /opt

RUN apt-get update -y
RUN apt-get install -y build-essential zlib1g-dev libncurses5-dev libgdbm-dev libnss3-dev libssl-dev libreadline-dev libffi-dev wget curl


RUN wget https://openssl.org/source/openssl-1.1.1d.tar.gz

RUN tar -xvf openssl-1.1.1d.tar.gz

WORKDIR openssl-1.1.1d/

RUN ./config --prefix=`pwd`/local --openssldir=/usr/lib/ssl enable-ssl2 enable-ssl3 enable-ssl3-method no-shared

RUN make depend

RUN make

RUN make -i install

RUN cp local/bin/openssl /usr/bin/


WORKDIR /opt
RUN curl -O https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.7.3/Python-3.7.3.tar.xz
RUN tar -xf Python-3.7.3.tar.xz


WORKDIR /opt/Python-3.7.3

RUN bash /opt/Python-3.7.3/configure --enable-optimizations --enable-shared --with-openssl=/usr/lib/ssl
RUN make -j 8
RUN make altinstall
RUN apt-get -y install python3-pip


WORKDIR /opt


COPY ./init.sh  /opt
RUN chmod +x /opt/init.sh
ENTRYPOINT "./init.sh"
```

But without any success.

```
 
>>> import ssl
>>> ssl.HAS_SSLv2
False
```

I need to tell python3.7 to use this openssl version, Can someone help me please ?

Thanks in advance.